# Add new custom view in django_chroniker package

Tags: django, cron

I need to create the simple view with some code and add it into cron jobs.

From admin side, user just allow to select the custom commands from "command" drop down

[image]

Can anybody, please help me? For adding custom view and displaying it on admin side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: some more context for this would be great here. Also what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this.

Created new test-simple_cron.py file with Command class and inside handle write down the required view code.

test-simple_cron.py

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print 'test simple cron'
```

Added this file into package commands folder, it automatically add this new custom command to commands drop down from admin side.

Also customize admin.py file for restricting values to command drop-down, display only "Chroniker" app commands.